# How to create routes to plugins after initialization

Tags: vue.js, codeigniter, vuejs2, vue-router, codeigniter-4

guys. I'm working on a modular admin system, based on Codeigniter 4 (as backend) and Vue.JS as frontend.

The main requirement for Codeigniter is that the system be completely modular, that is, by deleting a folder – you can remove, say, blog (news) management, or vice versa - add a file module and manage files (let's say – it's plugins, a bit like wordpress).

The main problem is that I want to make a SPA (single page app), and vue router requires a list of routes when it's init. At the login stage, I know that there are only standard (mandatory) pages: login, forgot (password reset), dashboard, settings (user settings). The backend will show other plugins only after successful authorization (example): news, pages manager, items (manage shop items) etc. And each of them can have several more routes for managing inside: create (add new record to database), edit, delete, view (card of record).

Is it possible to implement this with Vue router so that we get a SPA? Or can SPA be implemented only with a static (when it is clear how many pages there will be) project?

For better understanding, my plugins have all the necessary structure and are completely independent. Previously, when I didn’t use the Vue.js router, PHP went through all the plugin folders and collected a link (it creates array with links and at the header template I go through this array) to them for the menu , let's say from a file menu.php, in which was link (for example only):

```
<?php

    $menu['main'][] = array(
                'type' => 'item',  // item or sub-item for menu
        'link' => MODULES_URL.'pages/items',  // link to main page of plugin (by default list of records for this plugin)
        'title' => 'Pages Manager',  // name of page
        'active' =>  ($this->uri->segment(3) == 'pages'), // is active link? for menu
        'icon' => 'fa fa-pencil-square' // icon for menu
    );          

?>
```

Comment: "system be completely modular, that is, by deleting a folder" - for JS app this could be achieved by automatically rebuilding the app, since Vue apps are supposed to be built any way. It doesn't fit well the suggested simplistic workflow like uploading a module via FTP. " vue router requires a list of routes when it's init" - you could define it dynamically and reload the app in a browser when it changes, or you could use dynamic routes but they are less straightforward to work with. The point is that the list of routes should be known at the time when createRouter is called

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for response! I understand this, that's why I ask is it a good idea to use SPA at this project... 

I see only one solution: get all routes from backend with axios, but i don't understand how to build component (plugin/module) own routes (ex: when i go to blog, i must have create/edit/delete/view routes).

Comment: I don't see why it's bad. It may be bad because of other requirements, like you don't want to involve JS build process and keep it the way WP, etc usually works. There are many ways in which this could be done, including how plugin scripts could interchange data. The simplistic way is that they push their routes to `window.myRoutes` and after all plugin scripts are loaded, it's expected that myRoutes contains all the routes the app should be initialized with. Probably https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable for this kind of questions